# Android FIle Picker is not showing the checkbox to select only 1 directory when EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE is set to false

Tags: android, android-intent, nononsense-filepicker

I'm using the NoNonsense-FilePicker module from:

https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker

so I can apply an already made solution to pick files and directories for my current App.
It uses the common settings to modify its behavior. When I use it to pick multiple files and directories, it works fine, with the settings like:

```
Intent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_MODE, FilePickerActivity.MODE_FILE_AND_DIR);
Intent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

But when I want the File Picker to choose only 1 directory, so the configuration is:

```
Intent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_MODE, FilePickerActivity.MODE_DIR);
Intent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
```

it doesn't work because to the right of any directory it isn't showing the respective CheckBox to make the selection. So is that a bug of the NoNonsense-FilePicker library or is it a bug in Android? or am I missing something here?

Can you propose an easy solution? Maybe overriding something or adding an unknown (for me) condition or command? Thanks for reading this question.